# Github Webhooks for Public Repo Creation

Tags: github, github-api, webhooks

Is it possible to set up a Webhook to notify me every time a new repo is created on the whole public environment of Github (not limited to an specific organisation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible currently. If you'd like to share your use-case for this, please get in touch with us: https://github.com/contact